# how to disable sound in my game app?

Tags: android, audio, toggle

Now i develop a game application and as all games on google play, they have a toggle button to switch on/off the sound.

Is there any technique i can use to disable all sounds in the game with one step or i have to disable every sound separately ??

I use MediaPlayer for playing sounds

```
private int playSound(int file) {

    int duration = 1000;
    sound = new MediaPlayer();

    AssetFileDescriptor fd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(file);
    try {
        sound.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(), fd.getLength());
        sound.prepare();
        sound.start();

        sound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // Do the work after completion of audio
                Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "good", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mp.release();
            }
        });
        duration = sound.getDuration();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return duration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   media.setVolume(0,0);
```

Comment: and what about other sounds like default buttons sound ?